# How to get rid of many if null checks - c#

Tags: c#, null

How could I refactor this code to get it more cleaner:

```
public List<TestDTO> Map(product product)
{
    if (product == null || product.Tests == null || !product.productTests.Any()) return null;

    return product.productTests.Select(x => _productService.Map(x)).ToList();
}
```

Is it possible to write this more cleaner?

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: Is this your real code?

Comment: @Heslacher Nop, just playing around

Comment: If the code is not real, then the question is **off-topic**. See https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3649/my-question-was-closed-as-being-off-topic-what-are-my-options/3652#3652

Comment: It might be better to ask questions like this on stackoverflow.com, but search stackoverflow.com first to see if it has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to stop passing `null` values around everywhere. That would require changes much wider than the scope of this method though.

The biggest thing that can be won here is the `?.` operator. If the left hand side is `null`, the result will be `null` as well:

```
product?.productTests?.Select(x => _productService.Map(x))?.ToList();
```

will remove the need for the first two null checks.

Returning a `null` instead of an empty list is... questionable, but if you must return `null` you can check afterwards:

```
public List<TestDTO> Map(product product)
{
    var list = product?.productTests?.Select(x => _productService.Map(x))?.ToList();
    if (list?.Count == 0) return null;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: isn't this enought ? `return product?.productTests?.Select(x => _productService.Map(x)).ToList();` if any of this is `null`, `null` will be returned, otherwise data..

Comment: @Roxy'Pro I made a mistake, it should be `?.ToList` as well. Note that this is functionally different from your code, which also returns `null` when `product.productTests` is empty.

Comment: If `list` is null, an exception is thrown on `if (list.Count == 0) return null;`.

Comment: @RickDavin good point. `list?.Count` it is :)